# Using an arraylist for multiple if conditions

Tags: android, if-statement, arraylist

**I changed my mind about using swipemotions: As it is rather complicated to use swipemotions, I decided to just use simple buttons with 'bigger' and 'smaller'**

I'm currently working on a school project in Android Studio and so far I've written a code which generates a random equation. 
Here is the code which gereates the random equation:

```
String[] operationSet = new String[]{"+", "-", "/", "*"};
String stringResultOfEquation;
String equation;
double doubleAnswer1;
public void start1() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int numOfOperations = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

    List<String> operations = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
        String operation = operationSet[random.nextInt(4)];
        operations.add(operation);
    }

    int numOfNumbers = numOfOperations + 1;
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNumbers; i++) {
        int number = random.nextInt(10)+1;
        numbers.add(number);
    }

    String equation = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
        equation += numbers.get(i);
        equation += operations.get(i);
    }
    equation += numbers.get(numbers.size() -1);

    TextView TextEquation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextEquation.setText(equation);

    String stringResultOfEquation = String.valueOf(equation);

    double doubleAnswer1 = eval(stringResultOfEquation);

    String stringAnswer = Double.toString(doubleAnswer1);

    TextView textAnswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textAnswer.setText(stringAnswer);
}
```

Now the app displays two equations on the screen and the user then has to dicide wether the second equation has a bigger or smaller result than the first one. If the second equation is bigger, the user has to do a swipemotion UP and if the second equation is smaller, the user has to do a swipemotion DOWN. 
However I don't know how to write the code for this. I tried this:

```
if((doubleAnswer1 > doubleAnswer2) && (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN = true)){
    //create new equation
    }
```

but that didn't work. It told me that "Operator && can't be applied to boolean, int"

Now I'm curious if I could use an arraylist like this:

```
if(doubleAnswer1 > doubleAnswer2){
        // put "smaller" to arraylist
    } else {
        // put "bigger" to arraylist
    }

    if(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN = true){
        // put "smaller" to arraylist
    } 
    if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP = true){
        // put "bigger" to arraylist
    }
```

Then the code would check the arraylist if the elemnts of the arraylist are the same. If so, the next equation will be generated. If the elemnts of the arraylist are different, the process will be stopped.
I really don't know if that would work, so could someone maybe tell me if?
Or is there an other way to solve my problem?

If anything is unclear in my question, feel free to ask and I will try to clarify the problem :)

Thank you already in advance for your help!

Comment: Warning...  `if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP = true){` isn't a boolean comparison

Comment: It should be: event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP

Comment: I believe you are asking how to detect a swipe event?

Comment: **I changed my mind: As it is rather complicated to use swipemotions, I decided to just use simple buttons with 'bigger' and 'smaller'. But thank you for your help nevertheless**

Answer (score 1):

When you write such statement editor will tell you (Android studio hope so) that you can't compare int with boolean. as it is tendency that zero means false and 1 means true but in java you can't do like that.

you can try like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {


        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope will help in understanding...

Answer (score 0):

"=" is an assignment, 
for comparing a value use "==".

regarding recognizing gesture, check out https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

You need something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
    ...
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    Log.d(TAG, "fling! - direction is " + (velocityY > 0 ? "down" : "up"));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: And never ever write `someBoolean == true`

Comment: And can I now use this to detect a swipemotion? And if so, how can I detect it and then for example for a swipemotion UP that it puts "bigger" to an arraylist?

Comment: when creating the GestureDetectorCompat you pass the listener of gestures as a parameter (in my example it's "this", you'll need to extend GestureDetector.OnGestureListener), the onFling will be called whenever the user flings his finger up or down, you can use velocityY to determine the direction of the fling.